# query to update one table from another table using datetime interval difference

Tags: postgresql, datetime, join

I have two tables -

```
Table - 1

 prev_m | next_m | prev_order | next_order | prev_loc | next_loc |      datetime       | prev_datetime |    next_datetime    | id
--------+--------+------------+------------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------+---------------------+------
        | 6      |            |      308   |          |   222.5  | 2023-07-08 11:14:46 |               | 2023-07-08 11:15:33 | 101
        | 3      |            |      672   |          |   3.020  | 2023-07-08 16:17:56 |               | 2023-07-08 16:22:56 | 105

Table - 2 

   m  | orders|   loc  | message_id |    datetimestamp    | id
------+-------+--------+------------+---------------------+--------
  0   |    11 |  0.000 |         24 | 2023-07-08 11:14:13 | 101
  6   |   308 |  0.000 |         36 | 2023-07-08 11:14:25 | 107
  0   |    70 |  0.000 |         24 | 2023-07-08 11:14:28 | 105
  5   |   672 |  7.100 |         36 | 2023-07-08 11:14:30 | 101
  0   |  3418 |  0.000 |         24 | 2023-07-08 14:23:39 | 106
  3   |  3428 |  0.000 |         36 | 2023-07-08 15:23:41 | 101
  0   |  1899 |  0.000 |         24 | 2023-07-08 16:13:22 | 101
  0   |  1894 | 75.000 |         36 | 2023-07-08 16:14:34 | 101
  0   |    12 |  0.000 |         24 | 2023-07-08 16:15:49 | 105
  6   |   121 |  0.000 |         36 | 2023-07-08 16:16:01 | 101
  8   |  1528 | 50.000 |         36 | 2023-07-08 16:16:33 | 105
  0   |   15  |  7.020 |         24 | 2023-07-08 16:18:20 | 109
```

I want to update table -1 only null values from table -2 using below conditions -

- For same 'id' update 'prev_datetime', if table-1 datetime is greater than table-2 'datetimestamp' and difference between 'datetime' & 'datetimestamp' within 30 mins WHERE 'message_id' = 24.
- For same 'id' update 'prev_m ', 'prev_order' & 'prev_loc', if table-1 datetime is greater than table-2 'datetimestamp' and difference between 'datetime' & 'datetimestamp' within 30 mins WHERE 'message_id' = 36.

Output (table-1)-

```
prev_m | next_m | prev_order | next_order | prev_loc | next_loc |      datetime       |     prev_datetime    |    next_datetime    | id
--------+--------+------------+------------+----------+----------+---------------------+----------------------+---------------------+------
   5    | 6      |   672      |      308   |  7.100   |   222.5  | 2023-07-08 11:14:46 |  2023-07-08 11:14:13 | 2023-07-08 11:15:33 | 101
   8    | 3      |   1528     |      672   |  50.000  |   3.020  | 2023-07-08 16:17:56 |  2023-07-08 16:15:49 | 2023-07-08 16:22:56 | 105
```

I tried below query but it's not working -

```
UPDATE table_1 AS c1 JOIN table_2 c2 ON c1.id = c2.id SET 
    c1.prev_datetime = CASE WHEN c2.message_id='24' AND c1.prev_datetime IS NULL THEN c2.datetimestamp ELSE NULL END,
    c1.prev_order = CASE WHEN c2.message_id='36' AND c1.prev_order IS NULL THEN c2.orders ELSE NULL END,
    c1.prev_loc = CASE WHEN c2.message_id='36' AND c1.prev_loc IS NULL THEN c2.loc ELSE NULL END,
    c1.prev_m = CASE WHEN c2.message_id='36' AND c1.prev_m IS NULL THEN c2.m ELSE NULL END
    WHERE c1.datetime > c2.datetimestamp AND c1.datetime BETWEEN c2.datetimestamp AND c2.datetimestamp + interval '30 Minutes';
```

Demo - https://dbfiddle.uk/dDETRNid

Comment: Please provide example input data as executable SQL to make it easier for others to setup the problem conditions. Instead of saying, "it's not working," provide the error message or erroneous output. Since the syntax of the `UPDATE` statement as provided is invalid, I assume that PostgreSQL is reporting a `syntax error at or near "JOIN"`.

Comment: @JohnH..yes getting syntax error at 'JOIN'. Also, I have added the demo link in the main post. Thank you.